# plone with collective.flowplayer - video not appearing

Tags: video, flv, plone, flowplayer

I'm trying to setup some basic video sharing on my site using:

Plone 4.0.7 on Windows 7
collective.flowplayer 3.0rc4
test file:  http://blip.tv/file/get/KimAronson-TwentySeconds1318.flv

The player does not show up when I view a single file (setting display to flowplayer does not help), just a message about making sure javascript/flash are enabled.  This happens in both firefox and IE9; I don't think it's a browser settings or flash issue because I can see the player here just fine (in both browsers):

http://static.flowplayer.org/demos/plugins/javascript/playlist/horizontal.html

Any help appreciated!  I'll paste my buildout deets if that helps:

```
eggs =
Plone
products.ploneboard
products.ploneformgen
products.carousel
collective.quickupload
collective.plonetruegallery[all]
collective.prettyphoto
Products.ImageEditor
zettwerk.ui
collective.flowplayer


[versions]
Cheetah = 2.2.1
Paste = 1.7.2
PasteDeploy = 1.3.3
PasteScript = 1.7.3
ZopeSkel = 2.15
collective.buildout.cluster = 0.6
collective.recipe.backup = 1.3
iniparse = 0.3.1
plone.controller = 1.8
plone.recipe.command = 1.0
plone.recipe.distros = 1.5
plone.recipe.unifiedinstaller = 0.9 #4.0a1
distribute = 0.6.15
plone.app.jquerytools = 1.2
python-dateutil = 1.5
zettwerk.ui <= 0.4
```

Comment: Sounds like a JS issue, please check firebug and check if all the JS files are being loaded successfully and if there are any JS errors.